# scrolling to div inside absolute positioned parent div with changing height

Tags: jquery, dynamic, scroll, position

Here's my body:

```
body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:auto;
   /* aesthetic stuff */
}
```

Here's the `.page` div:

```
.page
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    margin-top:60px;
    z-index:1;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;   
    /* aesthetic stuff */
}
```

Here's the list item `div`

```
.item
{
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /* aesthetic stuff */
}
```

Here's some `HTML`:

```
<body>
    <div id="pages-1" class="page"></div>
</body>
```

`.page` gets filled dynamically with an unspecified number of these:

`<div class="item">Unique Item Content</div>`

When you click on an `.item` div, an unspecified number of other `.item` divs get `.hide()` called on them, to filter them out. I then scroll the clicked `.item` to the top of the `window`, no problem.

But when you click on the selected `.item` again, to unselect it, all the `.item` instances that were previously hidden now get `.show()` called on them, sending the previously selected, now unselected `.item` to a new position relative to `.page` and to `window`.

I don't have an issue scrolling to the top of selected `.item` when you first select it. But on `.item` instances that live toward the bottom of the unfiltered set of `.item` divs, when you unselect it I cannot get it to scroll to the top of that item *at all*. I can't even get anywhere close. **EDIT:** When I say I can't get it anywhere close, I mean, it's not even in the viewport by a mile. **END EDIT** Now on `.item` instances that are *not* toward the bottom of the set of divs, scrolling to it upon unselect mostly works. But on an `.item` toward the bottom, not close.

I've tried using its current `($(el).position()).top` after it is unselected, I've tried storing its original `position.top` in jQuery `data` when it is first selected, prior to filtering out the other `divs`. I've tried combinations of things.

I'm starting to think it's a lost cause. Maybe it has to do with `.page` being `absolute` positioned, but I can't change that for other reasons.

**UPDATE**

Further tests:

```
// $('.item.certain-ones').not(el).hide(); or $('.item').not(el).show(); here
alert($(el).position().top);
$('.page').scrollTop($(el).position().top);
alert($(el).position().top);
```

Results:
 - On Select: 140, then 0
 - On Deselect: 0, then 1700

So I tried running the `scrollTop` twice, to see what shakes out:

```
// $('.item.certain-ones').not(el).hide(); or $('.item').not(el).show(); here   
alert($(el).position().top);
$('.page').scrollTop($(el).position().top);
alert($(el).position().top);
$('.page').scrollTop($(el).position().top);
alert($(el).position().top);
```

Results:

1. On Select: 140, then 0, then 140
2. On Deselect: 1240, then 0, then 1240 (not visible in viewport at
   end)

But...

If after selecting the `.item`, I manually scroll UP just a little bit, the item stays exactly where it was in the viewport on deselect:

1. On Select: 140, then 0, then 140
2. Scroll up a tad ...
3. On Deselect: 73, then 1167, then 73 (perfectly in viewport, as if
   the other elements had not just been shown above and below it; it
   doesn't even move visibly).

However, if I manually scroll DOWN a tad, the results are the same as if I didn't manually scroll at all (see above, e.g., 1240, then 0, then 1240), i.e., not close to being visible in viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my various tests, particularly where when I manually scrolled up, it somehow reset the viewport so that `$(this).position().top` became "recognized." I don't know how to explain it, but I tried this and it solves my problem 100% and scrolls directly to the precise top of the unselected element every single time:

```
$('.page').scrollTop(0).scrollTop($(el).position().top);
```

where `el` is the clicked `.item`.

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on `.page` to the `.item` top:

```js
var hide = false;

$('.item').click(function(){
  if(hide){
    $('.item').show();
    $('.page').scrollTop($(this).position().top);
  }else{
    $('.item:nth-child(2n)').not(this).hide();
    $(this).show();
  }
  hide = !hide;
});
```

```css
body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:auto;
   /* aesthetic stuff */
}
.page
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    margin-top:60px;
    z-index:1;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;   
    /* aesthetic stuff */
}

.item
{
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /* aesthetic stuff */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="pages-1" class="page">
      <div class="item">Unique Item Content1</div>
      <div class="item">Unique Item Content2</div>
      <div class="item">Unique Item Content3</div>
      <div class="item">Unique Item Content4</div>
      <div class="item">Unique Item Content5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. That's the first method I tried. After showing the other divs, and scrolling to the top of the clicked .item, the .item is several hundred pixels south of the viewport.

Comment: You used with `.position().top` or `.offset().top`? If you're using the second one, you need to subtract the element `.height()`.

Comment: I've tried both. See my most recent update in the OP. This behavior is crazy hard to comprehend.

Comment: Subtracting the element height (80px) or not, it's out of viewport by over a thousand pixels.

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you've done on js? And what is the average size of what goes into the `.item`?

Comment: The item is 80px in height. That's the size always. 

The complete javascript is extremely complicated and would be a distraction, but it amounts to some `.item` instances get hidden, and some don't. Then after all the hiding (on select) or showing (on deselect) is done, I attempt to do this scroll we're talking about.

Comment: I found a really simple solution. See my answer.

Comment: That's nice!
But can you try something? Remove the `.scrollTop()`.

Comment: Sure, but which one? Replace it with what?

Comment: Just remove `scrollTop()` when you click to show the hidden divs.

Comment: Oh, Well I know what that does. That's why I resorted to scrollTop in the first place. It pushes the clicked div out of viewport.